# Remove a value from Firebase Array

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have a array in firebase created using the push() function.

I am trying to remove a specific value in that array.

```
var arr = $firebaseArray(ref.child('invoices').child('pending').child(coId));

arr.$loaded().then(function(){
    var index = arr.$getRecord(invoiceId);
    arr.$remove(index);
})
```

However, this is not working.  I keep getting -1 for the var index. If there is an easier way to remove a value, with or without angularFire, I would be open to it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I made a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/j351BkmsArfNLyoguSND?p=preview) for your case and it works:

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://benjaminsuch.firebaseio-demo.com/'),
    arr = $firebaseArray(ref.child('invoices'));

  arr.$loaded().then(function() {
    var index = arr.$getRecord('item123423');
    console.log('index', index);

    arr
      .$remove(index)
      .then(function() {
        console.log('item removed')
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log('error', error);
      });
  });
```

Maybe you provide us a plunker too with your code, so we can see whats going on.

Comment: Does invoiceId actually have a value? Because -1 means there have been no results found.